# Space used by /home does not match df -h

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-space-utilization, home-directory

I am seeing a big constant increase in the space amount taken in the `/home` directory

`df -h` says:

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        127G   52G   70G  43% /home`

However, once I am in the `/home` directory,  `du -hs * | sort -h` indicates the sum of the directories is about 20G

Therefore there is 30G of data I can't identify the origin of.

What should I look for to identify such a discrepancy between what `df -h` says and the actual content of the `/home` directory?

Edit: restarting nginx fixed the problem after using `lsof | grep "/home" | grep deleted` to identify what process was still using deleted files in memory

Comment: I am not sure to understand what "Check for files on located under mount points" means : should I check for files size inside the /home directory?

Comment: `/home/` is an ordinary directory on your root `/` file-system and like any other directory it can have subdirectories and files. When the /dev/md2  file-system is mounted on `/home`, then it becomes a mount point and you won't see those subdirectories and files anymore, they are hidden *under* the file-system of /dev/md2. But that would only be relevant if you were investigating disk usage on your root file-system.

Comment: In this case: `*` does not match hidden directories on `/home/`, check for those and from the linked duplicate: check for deleted files still in use by  open file descriptors with `lsof`